# shortcut recorder description

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, keyboard-shortcuts, record

I've heard about shortcut recorder, but not sure about it, do somebody can tell me what it is for sure?

Can I use it to know what shortcut I have pressed before?

Answer (score 3):

It's a nice cocoa control for recording hotkeys.
http://code.google.com/p/shortcutrecorder/ for more infos

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i can't get the code, can you give me another link?

Comment: svn checkout http://shortcutrecorder.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ shortcutrecorder-read-only